# PHP Source Query works on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, steam

I have used this https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Source-Query API for querying ARK server information on a website. Everything works perfectly on localhost, but not when uploaded on the web server. PHP works otherwise on the server, but not just this one feature. The Apache error log on server says this when the page is loaded:

> "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''xPaw/SourceQuery
>       /SourceQuery'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier 
>       (T_STRING) or function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) or \\ 
>       (T_NS_SEPARATOR) in /var/www/jamon/serverinfo.php on line 4, referer: 
>       https://jamonparadigm.com/servers"

The web server is running PHP 7. The serverinfo.php looks like this:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/SourceQuery/bootstrap.php';

use xPaw\SourceQuery\SourceQuery;

// For the sake of this example
Header( 'Content-Type: text/plain' );
Header( 'X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff' );

// The Island
define( 'SQ_SERVER_ADDR', '159.69.56.156' );
define( 'SQ_SERVER_PORT', 27000 );
define( 'SQ_TIMEOUT',     1 );
define( 'SQ_ENGINE',      SourceQuery::SOURCE );

$Query = new SourceQuery( );

try
{
    $Query->Connect( SQ_SERVER_ADDR, SQ_SERVER_PORT, SQ_TIMEOUT, SQ_ENGINE );

    $islandInfo =  $Query->GetInfo( );
    $islandPlayers = $islandInfo['Players'] . "/" . $islandInfo['MaxPlayers'];
    $islandVersion = trim(substr($islandInfo['HostName'], strpos($islandInfo['HostName'], '(')), "()");
    $islandStatus = '<span class="text-success">online</span>';
    $islandInfo2 = $Query->GetRules();
    $islandDay = $islandInfo2['DayTime_s'];
}
catch( Exception $e )
{
    $islandPlayers = "0/0";
    $islandVersion = "";
    $islandStatus = '<span class="text-danger">offline</span>';
    $islandDay = "";
}
finally
{
    $Query->Disconnect( );
}
?>
```

What could be done to fix the issue?

Comment: It may be a case of checking the `SourceQuery/bootstrap.php` to see if there is anything at the end of that which is causing the problem.

Comment: hmmm... Error message says that you have another line in your file on server than the one you've posted as a question. it says you have: `use 'xPaw\SourceQuery\SourceQuery';` with quoted namespace - which is wrong. Try to upload new file where make this line up or down to be sure that the version you hav on dev is the same as the one on your remote.

Comment: Ah, now I figured it out! The bootstrap.php had everything included with "require_once", and since my serverinfo.php page has multiple queries, all those had to be changed to "require". A stupid mistake, but thanks for helping me notice it.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] from your code. That said, as a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask].